Referencing an account from another within #[derive(Accounts)]
I am following this tutorial to build a lottery on Solana, which works totally fine on Solana Playground / https://beta.solpg.io/, but once i move the code to Visual code i'm getting some errors. Please help!! Here is the error i'm getting:
Error[E0425]: cannot find value `master` in this scope
   --> programs/btc/src/lib.rs:192:45
    |
192 |         seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &(master.last_id + 1).to_le_bytes()],
    |                                             ^^^^^^ not found in this scope



Here is the code:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateLottery<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = (4 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 1) + 8,
        seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &(master.last_id + 1).to_le_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [MASTER_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub master: Account<'info, Master>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Lottery {
        
        pub id: u32, // the id, 
        pub authority: Pubkey, // and who has auth over the lottery
        pub ticket_price: u64,
        pub last_ticket_id: u32,
        pub winner_id: Option<u32>, //(1+4) 
        pub claimed: bool,
   
        
}


I believe this should work. Isn't there some other omission in your code? Do you have the whole project published somewhere?

I don't have it published... but if u don't mind just popping this into anchor 0.30.0 it doesn't seem to work.
This part seems to compile fine if using anchor 0.29.0 but i'm seeing some other errors there, so i'm not 100% sure i've solved the problem.

I tried similar at 0.29.0 and it works (as you mentioned). I do not have direct experience with 0.30.0 but the changelog does not seem to be much helpful about it (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-1)

This is a known breaking change from Anchor 0.30.0. This means you have 3 options:

Use Anchor 0.29.0
Use one of the two workarounds I suggested here where I answered someone who had a similar issue to you.


I would mark this as duplicate and refer you to it that way, but cannot do this yet as the original asker on the other question hasn't upvoted or accepted my answer.

I can do that. Done.
